# What is the time zone for the time returned by backend.properties()?

Tags: programming, qiskit

For example, backend.properties() returns following:

```
{'last_update_date': '2019-11-11T07:16:13+00:00',
 'backend_name': 'ibmq_essex',
 'general': [],
 'qubits': ...
```

Is the above time UTC or local time(although in Essex it is the same value)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time you are looking at there, `last_update_time`, shows when the properties dict was last updated, so you can see whether it is a recent dict or an older one. This is why you are getting the same value for multiple backends.

This time is set [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ibmq-provider/blob/4cd1bf1980e79efac4eef07fe6937334c497d7fc/qiskit/providers/ibmq/api/rest/backend.py#L61) and so it shows the local date and time with the UTC offset, +0:00 in this case. All the times returned for the different properties are in UTC.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. I did not realize that +00:00 implies UTC.